# Finding a Keyword from a .txt file present in directories uploaded dynamically in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a project, which includes a .tar file will be uploaded on to UI it will be parsed by script and untarred Now this bundle will contain many folders, I need to access individually each folder and Search .txt files inside them for a keyword so that it displays the whole line containing the keyword on to the UI.

I have the following script which I'm using to search a keyword in different .txt files inside the folder but the logic fails to work when there are multiple folders and it needs to access the separate folders and display the keyword from .txt file of different folders

```js
<?php
$searchfor = $_GET['keyword'];



$file = array('alert_tool.INFO','alert_manager.INFO');
foreach($file as $name)
{

echo "\n"; echo"\n";
$contents = file_get_contents($name);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:<br />";
   echo implode("<br /> $name", $matches[0]);


}

else{
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
   echo nl2br ("\n\n\n\n\n No matches found in $file[$i]");
}
}
@fclose ($file); 

}


?>
```

any help is highly appreciated . Thanks.

Comment: how is the folder structure? like master-folder/
sub-folder1/ 1.txt, 2.txt . sub-folder2/ 1.txt, 2.txt?

Comment: @Plum - Thanks for replying, the folder structure is like a main master folder having sub folders which aren't fixed in number can be varying from 1 to 16. inside each folders there can be 1 to 24 .txt or .INFO files which i need to search,these files are also fixed in number but are in the range of 1-24.

so you can say it is like master folder/ sub folder / *.info or *.txt files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through codes from SO here nd there got this. This will read the files inside the master/sub/ folders by each

```
$searchfor = $_GET['keyword'];

$path = 'master-folder';

$dirs = array();

// directory handle
$dir = dir($path);

//This will have all the sub directories within the master-folder

while (false !== ($entry = $dir->read())) {
    if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
       if (is_dir($path . '/' .$entry)) {

            $dirs[] = $path . '/' .$entry."/"; 
       }
    }
}

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($dirs); exit; 


// This foreach is to read each sub folders inside the master-folder

foreach($dirs as $directory):

    //$linesToReturn = 4; // Set to four for the number of lines in each text file ( for expansion? )

    // Find all files in the directory which are .xyz files
    foreach( glob( $directory . "*.INFO" ) as $filename )
    {
        //echo $filename;

        // Open the file
        if( $handle = @fopen( $filename, "r") )
        {
            $x = 0; // Start the line counter

            // Cycle each line until end or reach the lines to return limit
            while(! feof( $handle ) )
            {
                $contents = fgets($handle); // Read the line

                // then match your search with the contents

                $x++; // Increase the counter
            }


        }
    }

endforeach;
```

Check and clarify please.

Comment: Plum, I got a few doubts here, Where exactly the code is accessing the sub folders for searching the file? Do i need to enter the complete path in $path= 'master-folder' entry.


Also, the comment where it says match your contents with search will that include my php script to match the keyword in file?

Comment: did you see a while loop at the top, with a commented statement //echo "<pre>"; print_r($dirs); exit;